# See all loaded .js files in Google Chrome debugger tool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, javascript-debugger

How can I see all `.js` files which were downloaded while showing my web page? I am using Network for it, but over time it stops showing `.js` files which were downloaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to the **sources** tab in Chrome, you'll see the a list of domains. Search for your own domain, for example 'localhost'. If you open the map, you'll see all folders and files that are loaded into your current page.

**Example:**

[image]

You'll also see all other domains where you've used files (like JS, CSS, images, etc.) from.

Answer (score 1):

## For a quick overview of all JavaScript files

you can **untick**

> ✔ Group by folder

to list all files sorted by type, so the `.js` filse are in one chunk, listed at or near the top, indicated by a yellow paper sheet icon.  (The gray-icon’ed html file, listed above the scripts, usually contains JS code as well, particularly within the `<head>` element.)

That option is in the *More options* menu (click <kbd>⋮</kbd> button) to the right of the sub-tabs, which start with `Page`, within the `Sources` tab.